# Using guards in list comprehensions

Tags: haskell

Trying to get :

```
removeAll :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
removeAll a b = [ | a /= i = i | i <- b ]
```

to work but keep getting parse errors. Am I using the guard correctly?

Comment: No, you are not. List comprehensions are explained in LYAH: http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
removeAll a b = [ i | i <- b, a /= i ]
```

You can also solve this using filter:

```
removeAll a = filter (/= a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
removeAll :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
removeAll a b = [ x | x <- b, x /= a ]
```